# ASP.NET table in session doesn't show elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

So basically what I want to do is that when a person enters his name and surname, I want to add them to a table so that a list(table) of registered people could be shown. As I am inexperienced in this technology, I tried to save my table in session, but when I load this saved table, I get only blank table in my browser. What am I missing here? And this is just for learning.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Session["lentele"] != null)
       {
            Table1 = (Table)Session["lentele"];        
       }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        duomenuSaugojimas(VardasTextBox.Text, PavardeTextBox.Text);
    }

    private void duomenuSaugojimas(string vardas, string pavarde)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell vardas1 = new TableCell();
        vardas1.Text = vardas;
        TableCell pavarde1 = new TableCell();
        pavarde1.Text = pavarde;

        row.Cells.Add(vardas1);
        row.Cells.Add(pavarde1);

        Table1.Rows.Add(row);

        Session["lentele"] = Table1;
    }
```

Comment: Where is declared `Table1`? In your aspx?

Comment: @krlzlx Yes, it is in aspx

Comment: If the table is a control on the page it will be different on each page load. You should save the data and create the controls based on that on each page load

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So I need to create a new table somewhere inside this code?

Comment: The table is created automatically on each page load so you have to add rows to it. If you store a table object to the Session, it will not be on the next pages loaded and adding rows to it won't show anything on the page

Comment: So how can i create these controls? Sorry for this stupid question @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: You save the data on Session and on Page_Load you add rows to the control you have on the aspx, just like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is true when a user want to see his own registration data. **Each user has his own session** and people can not see other people registration data in this way. If you want to do this you can use **Application** that shares to all, instead of session.

```
if (Application["lentele"] != null)
   {
        Table1 = (Table)Application["lentele"];        
   }
```

and at the end of your code:

```
Application["lentele"] = Table1;
```